# Is there any dataset which says whether a given sentence is a question or not?

Tags: nlp, dataset

I want to know if there are any publicly available datasets which contain questions and other sentences. I need it to build a question classifier -> a classifier which says whether a given sentence is a question or not. 
If there is no such dataset, what's the best way to go about building one?

I tried looking up online but could only find datasets which have different categories for a question or other text classification.

**EDIT**
I ended up using the CoQA dataset. I broke down the story sentences as non questions and used the default questions as questions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could take a dataset with question answering pair like [SQuAD dataset](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/) and then label every question to 1 and responses to 0. and then train amod

Comment: The dataset that I was referring to in the question was the SQuAD dataset. Most answers were 2-3 worded so they couldn't qualify as a non question. I ended up using the  [CoQA](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/coqa/) dataset. I broke down the story sentences as non questions and used the default questions as questions. Thanks for the reply!